# PHP File not printing HTML form content

Tags: php, html

I am taking an [HTML5 Tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=html5+tutorial). Part of the course discussing CSS3 and PHP.

In the PHP section, the instructor provides the following code to print the form input to the screen:

```
    <?php

    $usersName = $_GET['name'];
    $usersPassword = $_GET['password'];

    echo 'Hello ' . $usersName . '<br>';
    echo 'That is a great password ' . $usersPassword . '<br>';

    ?>
```

The HTML it refers to is:

```
        <form method="GET" action="phpscript.php">
            Your Name: <input type="type" name="name" size="50" maxlength="50"><br>
            Your Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
            Your history:<br>
            <textarea name="history" rows="20" cols="50">Just random words</textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
```

The PHP variables do not print to the page. This is the output:

```
echo 'That is a great password ' . $usersPassword . '<br>';
```

I double checked what the instructor had in the video, and it is exactly the same. Then, I opened the Console in Firefox and I saw an error on the PHP page that said that the doctype and character encoding was not declared. In the instructions, the instructor has a php file with only php code in it. So, I got rid of those two errors by using my html file as a template and adding the php code between my `<main></main>` tags, but got the same output. So, I added `<script type="text/php"></script>` around the php code, then nothing printed.

Please help me so I can continue moving forward in this tutorial. The instructor was using a Mac and Chrome and running the files locally. I am running everything locally in Windows 7 and Firefox. I tested things out using IE and Chrome but got the same results.

Thank you!!

Comment: do u have php? :O

Comment: Did you run this by entering a url in the browser **or** by double clicking the filename in explorer?

Comment: Do you have a web server? Does the web server have PHP configured

Comment: Are you using a local webserver (on your PC) or are you using a hosted server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like either you do not have php running anywhere (Since it is server side you need a server to run it and I recommend XAMPP for this use) or your file has the ending .html but you would need a .php to run php code. Just putting it in between the `<main>` tag won't work.

Comment: if I am just using the PHP on my computer for this course, not as a web server, should I download a full suite like XAMPP?

Comment: I know that you want to start right now but maybe you should check a little tutorial to xampp and webservers first (Why you need them and what you can do with them). 
https://blog.udemy.com/xampp-tutorial/ check the steps if you want to go ahead with your tutorial skip the explanations but I recommend you to read everything ;)

Answer (score 1):

For just startup you don't need a fully fledged web server , you can use PHP's inbuilt server simply go in php's installation directory save your php then bring a command prompt on this directory and run

```
php -S localhost:80
```

Now access file using http://localhost/file.php
You need to keep the shell open as long as you are using php

Answer (score 1):

You want to output the script without running it?

Try `<xmp></xmp>` 

For example, if you want to print a link like this, it will look like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

[Google](http://google.com)

but with the `<xmp>` tag, it looks like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```